# Getting data from JSON to JS

Tags: javascript, python, django

In the django function, I send data to JS via JSON

```
 startdate = datetime.strptime(request.POST['startdate'], '%d.%m.%Y')
 enddate = datetime.strptime(request.POST['enddate'], '%d.%m.%Y')
 paymentparking = paidparking.objects.filter(expirationdate__range = (startdate, enddate)).values('expirationdate',
                                                                                                   'price')
 return JsonResponse(dict(paymentparking))
```

How do I get price and expirationdate separately in JS?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "statistics",
    data: {
      'startdate': finalDateStrStart,'enddate': finalDateStrEnd,
    },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success:function (data) {
        
        }
    });
```

This is what I get in the django function before sending the JSON:

```
<QuerySet [{'expirationdate': datetime.date(2021, 4, 30), 'price': 300.0}, {'expirationdate': datetime.date(2021, 5, 5), 'price': 750.0}]>
```

If success:

```
function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        }
```

As a result, I get:

[image]

I need to get the price and expirationdate separately. How can this be done?

Comment: How does `data` look like?
   {
     expirationdate: ...
     price: ...
   }?

Comment: You should `console.log(data)` in the success function and inspect the result to figure out what parts of it to look up. If you have a specific question you can ask that. You need to do more debugging of your own problem first and be specific about what code you're running that isn't working.

Comment: Completed my question

Comment: @Tiago Yes, data looks exactly like this. I attached a data screen to the question

Comment: You should be able to use `data.price` and `data.expirationdate`

Comment: This seems more to do with the response generated by ~Flask~ err Django. I've tagged this with [tag:python] so you get the correct attention

Comment: @Phil This is Django, not flask

Comment: @Code-Apprentice good pickup, thanks for the edit. I have no idea where I got Flask from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get price and expirationdate separately in JS?

In your `success` function, you can access the properties of the first item as `data[0].expirationdate` and `data[0].price` for example. Since you are filtering `paidparking` instances, you should expect more than one.

The problem is that you are not correctly creating the JSON response. Converting a `QuerySet` to a `dict` won't do what you want. Instead, just serialize the `QuerySet` directly:

```
return JsonResponse(paymentparking, safe=False)
```

I set `safe=False` here in order to serialize the `QuerySet` as a JSON array.

Alternatively, you can serialize the `QuerySet` as a value inside a dictionary:

```
return JsonResponse({'result': list(paymentparking))
```

Then you can get the array of results through `data.result` in your `success` function. Do whatever you want with that array from there, such as `data.result[0].expirationdate` to get the expiration date for the first item.

For more information on `JsonResponse`, read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects).

Comment: And how can I get all the elements?

Comment: @Илья All of what elements?